# How to create a function that can be used in both node and browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I need to use the extend method, in node, I wrote:

```js
var Util = require('util');

Util._extend(a, b);
```

In browser, I use zepto, so I wrote:

```js
$.extend(a, b);
```

And I want to use only one file that can work both in node and browser, so I wrote:

```js
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // node
    var Util = require('util');
    Util._extend(a, b);
} else { // browser
    $.extend(a, b);
}
```

I use seajs in the browser, which implements the CMD API, so I wrote:

```js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = {
        init: function(){
            if (typeof exports !== 'undefined' && typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // the browser actually entered this block
                var Util = require('util');
                Util._extend(a, b);
            } else {
                $.extend(a, b);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The browser actually entered the first block, so the above code doesnt work, then I wrote:

```js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = {
        init: function(){
            var Util;
            if (Util = require('util')) { // the browser will try to require util, but util is a node module, so the browser won't find it, which will cause a 404 error
                Util._extend(a, b);
            } else {
                $.extend(a, b);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

It would cause a 404 error in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need use node module `browserify` for change backend code to frontend code